# Automatically Save File Dialog with Ruby / AutoIt / Watir

Tags: ruby, scripting, mozilla, watir, autoit

Ok, I am trying to use Watir/Ruby/AutoIt to automatically download a file. So say the dialog below pops up, my goal is to automatically click Save File, and then hit Ok. If someone could provide an example of how to do this I would be very much obliged. Thanks again.

[image: Mozilla save dialog]

Comment: From a brief look at the docs, I sincerely doubt that Watir supports complicated interactions like that...

Comment: [File Downloads](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/File+Downloads) page at Watir wiki has a few solutions.

Comment: Watir perhaps not, but I'm assuming that AutoIt does have some solutions by looking. It's just finding the specific solution for this problem that is causing the current trouble.